# WPF: Show PdfPage without Adobe/WebBrowser with native c#/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, uwp

I want to show `PdfPages` without any adobe or 3rd party application like the `WebBrowser` (which is an `activeX` control).

Based on the following example I have made a little `PdfViewer` where I can easily show `PdfPages`:

- https://blogs.u2u.be/lander/post/2018/01/23/Creating-a-PDF-Viewer-in-WPF-using-Windows-10-APIs

The strategy behind this example is to render each page into an `image` and show it directly with a `ContentPresenter`.

---

Now I my problem is the bad quality: There is some blurry effect.

Also setting `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);` does not solve the problem.

**Adobe Reader**
[image]
[image]

**My Solution**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the [Windows.Data.Pdf Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf) introduction, it is for converting a page in a Portable Document Format (PDF) document to an image file. The PDF will be blurred if it is not on the corresponding size.

In UWP, PDF APIs support high fidelity rendering, but only for C++ applications using Direct2D. You can refer this [PDF viewer showcase sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-showcase-sample-39ced1e8) to learn how to use it. But it seems you are creating a WPF app, you can have a try.

Note that: This is a Windows 8.1 app, VS2017 can not be used to open it, you can use VS 2013 or VS2015 and the API is similar as UWP apps.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is there a compiled version of the dll to directly import (`DLLImport`) and use it?

Comment: @DominicJonas There is the dll for that. The sample just for demonstrating how to implement the effect but it includes all the implemention for the effect, you can  follow and do it by yourself.

Comment: The link of the sample isn't valid.